# Check existence of elements in a class's array constants in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, constants

How can I check that a constant element like A\B::X['Y']['Z'] is set?

```
<?php

namespace A;

class B
{
    const X = [
        'Y' => [
            'Z' => 'value'
        ]
    ];
}

var_dump(defined('\A\B::X') && isset(\A\B::X['Y']['Z']));
```

`Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in [...] on line 13`

Comment: [isset](http://php.net/manual/it/function.isset.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 defined(A\B::X) returns true but defined(A\B::X['Y']['Z']) returns false :(

Comment: @Federico isset() triggers a fatal error.

Comment: you want to check if the constant exists AND if it has an element set?

Comment: `defined('A\B::X') && isset(A\B::X['Y']['Z'])`

Comment: @Federico Yes, I want to check that if A\B::X['Y']['Z'] is set, do something with it's value.

Comment: @Federico Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in [...] on line [...]

Comment: can you post the code, so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: @Federico I just updated my question.

Comment: I know this is related to PHP 5.6, but it is useful to know ```isset``` works with arrays that are constants in PHP 7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`isset` works only with variables. You can use the following code to check that `A\B::X['Y']['Z']` exists:

```
var_dump(
    defined('\A\B::X') &&
    array_key_exists('Y', \A\B::X) &&
    array_key_exists('Z', \A\B::X['Y'])
);
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering: ```isset``` works with arrays that are constants in PHP 7. Doesn't seem to be documented anywhere

Comment: Great to know, Ben Guest, thanks. Seemed illogical that isset did not work on constant arrays which were apparently SET to something. PHP team finally worked on this. :)

Answer (score 5):

Since `isset` works on variables (my bad) and not on arbitrary expression, you can use `array_key_exists` instead.

```
namespace A;

class B
{
    const X = [
        'Y' => [
            'Z' => 'value'
        ]
    ];
}

var_dump(array_key_exists('Y', \A\B::X) && array_key_exists('Z', \A\B::X['Y']));
```

Comment: Nice avatar by the way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You also can simply use:

```
var_dump(@\A\B::X['Y']['Z'] !== NULL);
```

The only caveat is you can't use it if your `const` may be defined to NULL.
In such a case, you could choose to rather give the `const` a `''`(empty string) value, which is pretty equivalent in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, but STFU operator is not an option according to our company's coding standards. Personally, I don't like using that too.

Comment: @user5483434 I know there is kinda religion about this. I agree to recommend not to use it without caution, but I firmly disagree with its total (and blind, IMO) ban. Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: Please don't be sorry bro, your solution didn't came to my mind at all and I really thank you for teaching me that. But according to our coding rules, we should not use that operator until there is other solutions that fits our needs, but we are not banned to use it on all cases, for example, there is a bug in PDO constructor that the only way to fix that, is using this operator, and we are allowed in such cases. Actually, while we are not fully banned, but we have used @ operator just to fix that bug in our many megabytes of PHP codes.

Comment: @user5483434 Thanks for the clarification, and for the kind words.

Comment: Currently the `@` error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use `@` to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I agree (obviously, since this is merely the excerpt from the PHP manual), but it precisely falls into what I called "kind a religion": in the current OP's case, it _can't_ happen that a critical error fires. So using it here keeps pretty secure.